# What is the proper way to stack ASM visitors?

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I have the following code:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ClassReader> e : classes.entrySet())
{
    ClassReader reader = e.getValue();
    ClassWriter writer = new ClassWriter(Opcodes.ASM7);

    // Process all visitors
    reader.accept(new StringRemapper(writer, "String A", "String A!!"), ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);
    reader.accept(new StringRemapper(writer, "String B", "String B!!"), ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);

    // Update the class
    reader = new ClassReader(writer.toByteArray());
    e.setValue(reader);
}
```

The issue with the code above is that it is writing everything twice, because there are two visitors writing to the same writer (I guess).

To fix this issue, I need to add the code below after every `reader.accept`:

```
reader = new ClassReader(writer.toByteArray());
writer = new ClassWriter(Opcodes.ASM7);
```

The thing is, by doing so, am I misusing the visitor pattern? I mean, why do I need to create a new reader/writer and **visit it only once**? Shouldn't I be able to have multiple visitors?

I found this similar question [Easy way to stack up a couple of ASM-Bytecode visitors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947484/easy-way-to-stack-up-a-couple-of-asm-bytecode-visitors) but couldn't understand the accepted answer.

I tried to pass the first visitor as a parameter to the second instead of the original ClassWriter, had the same result, duplicated code.

```
ClassVisitor last;
// Process all visitors
reader.accept(last = new StringRemapper(writer, "String A", "String A!!"), ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);
reader.accept(new StringRemapper(last, "String B", "String B!!"), ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);
```

Comment: `ClassVisitor cv = new StringRemapper(writer, ...); cv = new StringRemapper(cv, ...); reader.accept(cv, ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, you did miss something: The `ClassWriter` is a `ClassVisitor` itself.

The right way to stack the visitors is to pass it's parent visitor to the constructor:

```
// The root visitor is the ClassWriter
ClassVisitor cv = writer;

// Add a visitor
cv = new StringRemapper(cv, "String A", "String A!!");
// Add another one
cv = new StringRemapper(cv, "String B", "String B!!");
// maybe add more?

// Process them
reader.accept(cv, ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);
byte[] classFile = writer.toByteArray();
```

If your `StringRemapper` only takes a `ClassWriter` as parameter, then you should change it to accept `ClassVisitor`s instread.

Another thing I noticed is your `classes` variable: It contains `ClassReader`s as values.
It might be an easier design to use `ClassVisitors` as value - with an initial `ClassWriter` value.
But this is a bigger design change.